# JTS with lat/lon

Tags: latitude-longitude, spatial-index, jts

I'm having some spatial data that has all of its coordinates as lat/lon pairs (with about 10 digits decimal precision), it's stored in a database as WGS84 data.Some of the data is represented as polygons which are the resulting union of some smaller polygons whose boundaries are stored.Then I'm having a number of points from which I build a linesegments (just 2 points in each segment) which I use later for intersection tests with the polygons.

I'm using a SpatialIndex to improve my queries so I insert the envelopes of all polygons in a tree (tested with both QuadTree and STRtree).Then, I connect two points into a linesegment and I'm using its envelope to query the tree for possible intersections.The problem is that I get pretty much all the polygons as a result which is clearly wrong.. To give you some idea about the real scale of my data, I have about 100 polygons that cover the whole North america, each line covers a very very small part of a single polygon.Ideally, i would expect no more than 2 polygons as a result.

I'm using JTS to do this calculation and I'm aware that it's not really suited for spherical data so can you suggest me another library/tool to achieve the desired behaviour or possible a workaround (for example, projecting before using JTS)?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, would really like an answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have north america, just rotate earth by 90 degrees so that Alaska is no longer on the far east. (Fun fact: Alaska is both the most northern, western and eastern state of the U.S.) Then your rectangles should be okay.

There are a number of non-trivial cases though when working with spherical data. Depending on how your data is defined, your polygon borders may actually be bent lines, instead of straight lines. Consider this screenshot of Google Ingress: https://lh4.ggpht.com/S_9jrMqf08JfIbr7DgUDH96rvXMK4wOGtaSKYPGCruXv2HE4oeRuEaQIDIywMgH4198=h900

I read somewhere that the mismatch of the "fog" texture and the green line visible in the left field is due to the two drawing functions using different approximations. One is always a straight line, whereas the other follows the curvature of the earth. If you have a large field (polygon!), the error becomes worse.

"Intersection" becomes a tricky term when your data consists of non-straight lines on the surface of a sphere, unfortunately; and a "straight" line on the surface of earth will often yield an arctan type curve in latlon coordinates.

Projections: these can help, but mostly when your data is local. UTM projections are pretty good, but you need at least 9 UTM zones to cover north america *without* Alaska. As long as your data is within *one* UTM zone, projecting the data into this zone and then working with 2D euclidean space should work good. But if it gets lager than this, you may need to stitch different projections, and that is really messy, too.